# Apple_Thunderbolt_Display as 2nd Monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, mac, thunderbolt

Running Ubuntu 16.04.4, I'm trying to use an [Apple Thunderbolt Display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Thunderbolt_Display) as a 2nd Monitor for a [system76 bonobo laptop](https://system76.com/laptops/bonobo).

I'm confused by the cable that is built into the Apple Thunderbolt Display; it has a thunderbolt logo on the end that plugs into the laptop, but it is shaped like a mini-display port. Plugging it into either of the bonobo's mini-displayports doesn't lead to detection by Ubuntu `sudo xrandr -q`.

So, I assume that I need an adapter where I can ultimately plug this cable into the bonobo's (usb-c looking) thunderbolt ports that also showcase the thunderbolt symbol above the port ([shown here](http://neartalk.com/ss/2018-05-14_001_1776x1919.png) -- you can't really see the logo, in the photo, but it is there).

But, this is a weird adapter to find, because the cable's end only looks like mini-displayport, while it is really thunderbolt. I'm not sure that a regular mini-diplayport to thunderbolt adapter (one that really converts  mini-displayport to thunderbolt) would work (because it already is thunderbolt). I know I'm missing some essential understanding regarding the essence of connectors.

BTW, I have confirmed that Ubuntu 16.04.4 does work great with this monitor when I install Ubuntu 16.04.4 directly onto a mac mini (because the mac mini has the same strange situation; its female port looks like displayport, but it also is really thunderbolt!

Yes, I'm confused. Please advise.

Comment: This [article](https://www.cnet.com/news/confusing-mini-displayport-with-thunderbolt/) reduces some of my confusion.

Comment: Another [good article](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/usb-type-c-thunderbolt-3-one-cable-to-connect-them-all/) on the topic.

Comment: I ordered this [adapter](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/B01MQ26QIY/howtoadvicecom); I'll report back here if it works or not.

Comment: Hi @lonnie, I used this adapter from the SO question: https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-Thunderbolt-Adapter-Macbook-Compatible/dp/B019FPJDQ2/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1530571335&sr=8-1&keywords=startech+tbt3tbtadap

Comment: @LaserJesus: Just to be certain, are you saying you were able to connect an [Apple Thunderbolt Display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Thunderbolt_Display) to Ubuntu using [the adapter you've suggested](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/B019FPJDQ2/howtoadvicecom)? I couldn't get it to work with [the adapter I purchased](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/B01MQ26QIY/howtoadvicecom).

Comment: yes @lonnie I was able to get the Thunderbolt display working with a non-mac laptop running Ubuntu using the StarTech adapter. You will still need to setup a script to enable it properly though, as detailed here: https://superuser.com/questions/1210310/thunderbolt-display-not-recognised-with-ubuntu-16-04/1210677

Comment: @LonnieBest were you ever able to get this working with the Apple adapter you linked to?  I have the same one but no luck yet.

Comment: @Madbreaks : I did not. What's interesting, is that I've installed both Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 onto a MAC Mini, and that monitor works fine with Ubuntu as long as I have Ubuntu installed on the original MAC hardware. This monitor is a beautiful display for Ubuntu. What's strange, is it doesn't have a power button. It seem like the original MAC equipment knows something that adapters don't, like: "how to turn the damn thing on".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same boat.  We're out of luck, probably for good.  Details here:  https://github.com/intel/thunderbolt-software-user-space/issues/66#issuecomment-524586649