# Apple Thunderbolt Display on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: 18.04, display, apple, intel-nuc, thunderbolt

Running latest LTS Ubuntu on a new [Intel NUC](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/boards-kits/nuc/kits/nuc8i7beh.html)

I'm trying to get my Apple Thunderbolt display running. Since the NUC has TB3, I bought a [TB3 to TB2 adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B019FPJDQ2). The display does not fire up, and neither does anything connected to any of the ports on the display.

When I connect a firewire external HDD via an Apple Thunderbolt to Firewire dongle, Ubuntu recognizes and mounts the drive.

dmesg shows something interesting:

```
[33897.389990] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[33897.391553] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: NHI initialized, starting thunderbolt
[33897.391572] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: allocating TX ring 0 of size 10
[33897.391639] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: allocating RX ring 0 of size 10
[33897.391697] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: control channel created
[33897.391704] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: control channel starting...
[33897.391713] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: starting TX ring 0
[33897.391735] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: enabling interrupt at register 0x38200 bit 0 (0x0 -> 0x1)
[33897.391744] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: starting RX ring 0
[33897.391766] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: enabling interrupt at register 0x38200 bit 12 (0x1 -> 0x1001)
[33897.483380] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: current switch config:
[33897.483383] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:  Switch: 8086:15da (Revision: 6, TB Version: 2)
[33897.483385] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:   Max Port Number: 11
[33897.483386] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:   Config:
[33897.483388] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:    Upstream Port Number: 5 Depth: 0 Route String: 0x0 Enabled: 1, PlugEventsDelay: 254ms
[33897.483390] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:    unknown1: 0x0 unknown4: 0x0
[33897.526444] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: 0: uid: 0x8086ee424108a100
[33897.527850] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:  Port 0: 8086:15da (Revision: 6, TB Version: 1, Type: Port (0x1))
[33897.527856] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:   Max hop id (in/out): 7/7
[33897.527860] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:   Max counters: 8
[33897.527865] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:   NFC Credits: 0x800000
[33897.528357] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:  Port 1: 8086:15da (Revision: 6, TB Version: 1, Type: Port (0x1))
[33897.528363] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:   Max hop id (in/out): 15/15
[33897.528367] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:   Max counters: 16
[33897.528372] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:   NFC Credits: 0x3c00000
[33897.528869] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:  Port 2: 8086:15da (Revision: 6, TB Version: 1, Type: Port (0x1))
[33897.528873] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:   Max hop id (in/out): 15/15
[33897.528878] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:   Max counters: 16
[33897.528882] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:   NFC Credits: 0x3c00000
[33897.528887] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: 0:3: disabled by eeprom
[33897.528891] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: 0:4: disabled by eeprom
[33897.528896] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: 0:5: disabled by eeprom
[33897.529027] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:  Port 6: 8086:15da (Revision: 6, TB Version: 1, Type: PCIe (0x100101))
[33897.529032] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:   Max hop id (in/out): 8/8
[33897.529036] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:   Max counters: 2
[33897.529041] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:   NFC Credits: 0x800000
[33897.529125] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:  Port 7: 8086:15da (Revision: 6, TB Version: 1, Type: PCIe (0x100101))
[33897.529130] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:   Max hop id (in/out): 8/8
[33897.529134] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:   Max counters: 2
[33897.529138] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:   NFC Credits: 0x800000
[33897.529143] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: 0:8: disabled by eeprom
[33897.529284] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:  Port 9: 8086:15da (Revision: 6, TB Version: 1, Type: DP/HDMI (0xe0101))
[33897.529289] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:   Max hop id (in/out): 9/9
[33897.529293] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:   Max counters: 2
[33897.529297] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:   NFC Credits: 0x1000000
[33897.529381] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:  Port 10: 8086:15da (Revision: 6, TB Version: 1, Type: DP/HDMI (0xe0101))
[33897.529386] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:   Max hop id (in/out): 9/9
[33897.529390] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:   Max counters: 2
[33897.529394] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0:   NFC Credits: 0x1000000
[33897.529399] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: 0:b: disabled by eeprom
[33897.665976] pcieport 0000:03:02.0: Primary bus is hard wired to 0
[33897.666004] pci_bus 0000:6d: [bus 6d] partially hidden behind bridge 0000:03 [bus 03-6c]
[33897.666012] pci_bus 0000:6d: [bus 6d] partially hidden behind bridge 0000:02 [bus 02-6c]
[33897.666052] pcieport 0000:03:02.0: Primary bus is hard wired to 0
[33897.666079] pci_bus 0000:03: Allocating resources
[33898.708909] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: switch at 1.1 was rejected by ICM firmware because topology limit exceeded
[33899.341988] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: switch at 2.1 was rejected by ICM firmware because topology limit exceeded
```

The `topology limit exceeded` lines seem troubling, but there are certainly [others in the forums](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036356/apple-thunderbolt-display-as-2nd-monitor) that seem to have gotten this display working.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the thunderbolt settings in BIOS, set thunderbolt to BIOS assist, instead of native mode.

Comment: Saw elsewhere a setting like that for a Dell laptop maybe? My NUC BIOS does not have a BIOS assist / native mode setting for thurderbolt.

Comment: Can confirm that changing said setting worked on a DELL XPS 15 9570 with an Apple Thunderbolt2 27'' display and a Thunderbolt-2-to-Thunderbolt-3 adapter.